# Javascript loop not completing

Tags: javascript, xml, cordova

**Solved**-My code didn't use var in all of the places it should. Adding this resolves the issue.

I'm trying to use a loop to go through the children nodes of a given "scene". In this example, it's scene 2. My code allows for "links" which essentially go and load the child nodes of another scene before coming back to the current scene and loading the remaining child nodes. The problem is, anytime I use a link, it will prevent the ORIGINAL scene from completing its loading.

**XML:**

```
<scene id="2">
    <content>Scene2-Content1</content>
    <content>Scene2-Content2</content>
    <link id="4"/>
    <choice content="Scene2-Choice1"/>
</scene>
<scene id="4">
    <content>Scene4-Content1</content>
    <choice content="Scene4-Choice1"/>
</scene>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = {
    loadScene: function (scene) {
        //find the scene and load the scene data
        if(app.storyXml != null)
        {
            sceneNodes = app.storyXml.getElementsByTagName("scene");
            for(i=0; i<sceneNodes.length; i++)
            {
                id = sceneNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
                if(id == scene)
                {
                    app.loadSceneData(sceneNodes[i]);
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
    },
    loadSceneData: function (scene) {
        childNodes = scene.childNodes;

        try
        {
            length = childNodes.length;
            for(i=0; i<childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                console.log((i+1)+"/"+childNodes.length);
                tag = childNodes[i].tagName;
                if(tag == "content")
                    app.loadSceneContent(childNodes[i]);
                if(tag == "link")
                    app.loadSceneLink(childNodes[i]);
                if(tag == "choice")
                    app.loadSceneChoice(childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    },
    loadSceneLink: function (node) {
        if(app.storyXml != null)
        {
            sceneNodes = app.storyXml.getElementsByTagName("scene");
            for(i=0; i<sceneNodes.length; i++)
            {
                id = sceneNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
                if(id == node.getAttribute("id"))
                {
                    app.loadSceneData(sceneNodes[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//loadSceneContent and loadSceneChoice omitted--they simply add some elements to the page.
```

In this specific example, loadSceneContent/loadSceneChoice are called for the first two content nodes in scene 2. After that, the link calls them for the content/choice node. I expect the control to return to the original loadSceneData loop, but it instead simply jumps to the end of the loop in the original loadSceneData call. I've banged my head against the wall and tried every variation I could think of. Nothing seems to work.

If I remove the link node, everything from scene 2 is loaded as expected.

I don't post on Stack Overflow often, so please let me know if I'm missing something essential to my question. I appreciate your help!

Comment: DECLARE YOUR VARIABLES WITH `var`. I'm pretty sure your variable `i` is conflicting between methods because it has become global. So in the problematic place, use `for(var i=0; i<sceneNodes.length; i++)`. There's probably also a conflict with `sceneNodes`

Comment: You just fixed it. Using var was the solution. I feel like a complete idiot...

My only consolation is that this is my first project in Javascript.

Comment: No problem. Now you know to always declare variables with `var` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring your loop variables `i` with `var` should fix any conflicts between calling methods. Without `var`, `i` is declared as a global variable...that means all methods will end up sharing its use. It would be fine if each method was called separately, but they are called within each's loop. If you call one method in the middle of another's loop, the value of `i` is modified, therefore messing up the containing loop.

As an example, your first loop should look like:

```
for(var i=0; i<sceneNodes.length; i++)
```